Is there way to make a list of all FB pages I liked?
I want to make myself a 2nd account. Is there any way to get a sorted list (preferably with title and link or just links) of all the pages I liked on the first account, so I can like them using the second account?
Perhaps using the API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v20.0/object/likes
I can do curl request, but idk how to get the access token or code it to parse the IDs in a list - it returns too much info per object.
I tried to do it on the app, but it's very inconvenient (have to open page, go back) and also it reloads the list every few minutes forcing me to start from the beginning, so I am looking for a easier option?
I didn't try much, just read the API and some Googling, but couldn't find a tool that can do what I need.
